Find a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ with row space U and column space V given in plane equations
Find a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ with row space $$U = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3: x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 = 0\}$$ and column space $$V = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3: x_1 - x_2 + x_3 = 0\}.$$
Here is my attempt:
So, first thing is that there exists such matrix because they both have dim = 2. I have re-arangged the plane equation by letting $x_1 = -2x_2 - x_3 $ for U and $x_1 = x_2 - x_3$ for V. And therefore the basis for the column space of the matrix will be $$U = \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}x_2 + \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}x_3$$ and the basis for the row space of the matrix will be $$V = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}x_2 + \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}x_3$$
So I know that the two columns of the matrix should include the two columns of the basis for the column space because the pivot column of the matrix determines which column in the original matrix A is the basis for the column space (?). But, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Assuming I understood your question correctly, what you need is the singular value decomposition.

Presumable you mean $\mathbb R^{3\times3}?$

Yes @Thomas Andrews

Consider the more general problem where you are given two $k$-dimensional subspaces $U$ and $V$, with orthonormal bases $\{u_1,\ldots,u_k\}$ and $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$, respectively, in $\mathbb R^n$ for some $1\le k \le n$. Then, the matrix
$$
A= \sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i v_i u_i^T
$$
has row space $U$ and column space $V$ as long as $\sigma_i\ne 0$. I’ll leave it to you to apply this to your specific problem.

what is sigma in this context? and how did you derive this?

It’s called a singular value of $A$. For your purposes it can be any non zero real number.

It’s a well known property of singular value decomposition that the column space of $A$ is generated by the $v_i$s and the row space of $A$ is generated by the $u_i$s as long as the corresponding singular values are nonzero.
